# Foursquare Realtime API - UserId vs Authentication relation

Tags: foursquare

During connected app integration user is redirected to a callback url provided by application developer. At the last step of authentication it is written that "Save this access token for this user in your database." . But the problem is you do no get userId during this authentication process.

https://developer.foursquare.com/overview/auth#access

I get authentication code but can not access userId. How can get userId of authenticating user...

regards..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have the access token, you can make a request to the [users/self](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/users/users) endpoint to get any information about the user associated with that token, including the user's `id`.

Comment: thank you @octopi, but my problem is associating access_tokens with  corresponding userIds. Although I get access_token I don't know the owner of it..

Comment: solved - https://api.foursquare.com/v2/users/self?oauth_token=ACCESS_TOKEN_STRING